# Replacing Certain Parts of a String Python

Tags: python, string

I can not seem to solve this. I have many different strings, and they are always different. I need to replace the ends of them though, but they are always different lengths. Here is a example of a couple strings:

```
string1 = "thisisnumber1(111)"
string2 = "itsraining(22252)"
string3 = "fluffydog(3)"
```

Now when I print these out it will of course print the following:

```
thisisnumber1(111)
itsraining(22252)
fluffydog(3)
```

What I would like it to print though is the follow:

```
thisisnumber1
itsraining
fluffydog
```

I would like it to remove the part in the parentheses for each string, but I do not know how sense the lengths are always changing. Thank You

Comment: Do you need to worry about, e.g., `"thishasparens(butnotanumber)"` or `"thishasunclosedparens(10"` or `"thishastwosets(10)(20)"` or `"thishasparens(123)thenmore(456)"` or anything else like that? If so, what do you want to do for each of those cases?

Comment: Nope, all that will be in the parentheses will be numbers :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) for this:

```
>>> string1 = "thisisnumber1(111)"
>>> string2 = "itsraining(22252)"
>>> string3 = "fluffydog(3)"
>>>
>>> string1.rsplit("(")
['thisisnumber1', '111)']
>>> string1.rsplit("(")[0]
'thisisnumber1'
>>>
>>> string2.rsplit("(")
['itsraining', '22252)']
>>> string2.rsplit("(")[0]
'itsraining'
>>>
>>> string3.rsplit("(")
['fluffydog', '3)']
>>> string3.rsplit("(")[0]
'fluffydog'
>>>
```

`str.rsplit` splits the string from right-to-left rather than left-to-right like `str.split`.  So, we split the string from right-to-left on `(` and then retrieve the element at index `0` (the first element).  This will be everything before the `(...)` at the end of each string.

Comment: To ensure the the operation is only on the end of the string you might want to restrict to a single split to handle strings like `"flu(ffy)dog(3)"`, e.g. `rsplit("flu(ffy)dog(3)", 1)`.

Comment: @mhawke: On the other hand, how do you know that `flu(ffy)dog` would be the desired output in that case, as opposed to `fludog` or `flu`? (That's why I asked the OP, who confirmed that none of these cases exist in his data, which means this answer is sufficient.)

Comment: @abarnert : in retrospect, yes. OP did state replacing the end of the string and my suggestion restricts it to that without assuming that the data does not contain any additional left parens.

Answer (score 1):

Your other option is to use regular expressions, which can give you more precise control over what you want to get.

```
import re
regex = regex = r"(.+)\(\d+\)"

print re.match(regex, string1).groups()[0] #returns thisisnumber1
print re.match(regex, string2).groups()[0] #returns itsraining
print re.match(regex, string3).groups()[0] #returns fluffydog
```

Breakdown of what's happening:

`regex = r"(.+)\(\d+\)"` is the regular expression, the formula for the string you're trying to find

`.+` means match 1 or more character of any kind except newline

`\d+` means match 1 or more digit

`\(` and `\)` are the "(" and ")" characters

putting `.+` in parentheses puts that string sequence in a group, meaning that group of characters is one that you want to be able to access later on. We don't put the sequence `\(\d+\)` in a group because we don't care about those characters.

`regex.match(regex, string1).groups()` gives every substring in `string1` that was part of a group. Since you only want 1 substring, you just access the 0th element.

There's a nice tutorial on regular expressions on Tutorial's Point [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in a comment:

> "all that will be in the parentheses will be numbers"

so you'll always have digits between your parens, I'd recommend taking a look at removing them with the regular expression module:

```
import re

string1 = "thisisnumber1(111)"
string2 = "itsraining(22252)"
string3 = "fluffydog(3)"

strings = string1, string2, string3

for s in strings:
    s_replaced = re.sub(
        r'''
        \( # must escape the parens, since these are special characters in regex
        \d+ # one or more digits, 0-9
        \)
        ''', # this regular expression will be replaced by the next argument
        '', replace the above with an empty string
        s, # the string we're modifying
        re.VERBOSE) # verbose flag allows us to comment regex clearly
    print(s_replaced)
```

prints:

```
thisisnumber1
itsraining
fluffydog
```